# Copying model output to a torch.Tensor where requires_grad is True

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, autograd

I have a model that outputs a sequence of vectors for each element in the batch, e.g., `[Batch size, Sequence Length, Hidden size]`. Then, I want to select a variable number of vectors for each element in the batch, and copy these vectors to a tensor where `requires_grad = True`. A sample code is bellow:

```py
from torch import nn
from typing import List

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(8,8)
    
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor, indices: List[torch.Tensor]):
        # Example indices: [torch.tensor([0,1]), torch.tensor([2,3,4])]
        out = self.fc(x)
        batch_size, _, hidden_size = out.size()
        max_num_hidden_states = max([ind.size(0) for ind in indices])
        selected_hidden_states = torch.zeros(batch_size, max_num_hidden_states, hidden_size, requires_grad=True)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            selected_hidden_states.data[i, :indices[i].size(0)] = out[i, indices[i]]
        return selected_hidden_states
    
model = MyModel()
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(torch.rand(2, 5, 8), [torch.tensor([0,1]), torch.tensor([2,3,4])])
```

The questions I have w.r.t. this are:

1. If I train such model, would the gradients be backpropagated in the rest of the model parameters?
2. Why does `output.requires_grad = True`, when I explicitly state `torch.no_grad()`?
3. The way I'm doing this (which it doesn't seem to work as expected as of now) seems too hacky and wrong. What is the proper way to achieve what I want?

I'm aware of [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-do-padding-based-on-lengths/24442/2), which approves my way doing it (at least it seems like it), but still it looks hacky to me.

Cheers!

Comment: `requires_grad=True` won't suffice to make the output of your model back-propagable. It needs to be *linked* by torch operators to your model's parameters, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy-paste an [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/copying-model-output-to-a-torch-tensor-where-requires-grad-is-true/129132/2?u=gorjanradevski) from the PyTorch forum.

That is from a time long gone and answering a different question.

1. No. Between creating a new tensor requiring grad and using .data, which you never should these days, you created a new leaf which will accumulate .grad.
2. Because you requested it. no_grad signals that you do not need the grad, it does not include guarantees about the requires_grad of the result.
3. If the utility function does not work for you, dropping the requires_grad and the .data should do the trick.